# An HtmlSelect cannot have multiple items selected when Multiple is false

Tags: asp.net

I am getting the below error

> An HtmlSelect cannot have multiple items selected when Multiple is false.

Why i am getting this error i don't understand still?

Comment: How did you get this error ? Please update your question.

Comment: when i am clicking on the link to open employee details i am getting this.

Comment: Please post some necessary HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to be able to select more than one value. The multiple property must be set to true

> Use the Multiple property to specify whether multiple items can be
>   concurrently selected in the HtmlSelect control.

```
<asp:HtmlSelect Multiple="True|False" />
```

[HtmlSelect.Multiple Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlselect.multiple.aspx)

Comment: I don't have <asp:HtmlSelect Multiple="True|False" /> in my page.but iam getting error

Comment: It should be a short comment and should ask user about the basic requirement first.

Comment: I am still wondering for help. Can any help me why this error occured?

Answer (score 2):

I got this error also. When I try to set selected value to select and when page finally loaded.

Problem was in my code. I set selected value as :

```
mySelect.Items.FindByValue(myValue).Selected = true;
```

It seems to work good and without any problems, but...

Later I update this code with :

```
mySelect.SelectedIndex = mySelect.Items.IndexOf(mySelect.Items.FindByValue(myValue));
```

and now it works.

I hope this will help somebody else.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Thank you